# How to validate font extension?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a file with `TTF` extension I need to validate

```
$request->validate([
       'font' => 'required|file|mimes:ttf',
  ]);
```

When I upload the `ttf` file the validation says The `font must be a file of type ttf`

For information, I already put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
$request->validate(['fontttf' => 'file|mimetypes:ttf,application/x-font-truetype,application/x-font-ttf,font/ttf']);
```